# Get data from the eager loaded object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

I am trying to eager load an object while fetching data from it in the same query. The query is below
`CycleDay.includes(:user).where(test_required: true, date: Date.today).where.not( :users => { :reader_id => nil }).pluck(:user_id, :users)`

Here, I am eager loading the User object where `CycleDay belongs_to :user`

The query is working fine, and it is returning a map consisting of the values [id, {user}], but instead of user I want to get the user.name (name column of the user object). Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: You already answered your own question. One small note, you return an Array now instead of an ActiveRecord::Relation. This means you cannot query it any longer (or apply another scope for example).

Just for explanation regarding the ActiveRecord::Relation:

```
example_collection = CycleDay.joins(:user).select('cycle_days.id, users.name AS user_name').where(test_required: true, date: Date.today).where.not( users: { reader_id: nil })
```

This returns an ActiveRecord::Relation with a bunch of objects, that only contain an id and user_name, because that is what you select in your query. So now I can call this:

```
example_collection.first.id
example_collection.first.user_name
```

pluck() converts a collection of objects into an Array and returns the results of the chosen attributes. You see all the ids and names in an Array now which is really convenient. However, you have an Array now, so the methods you can call on it are different then an ActiveRecord::Relation.

Another side note, regarding joins vs includes. Take this example:

```
example_with_includes = CycleDay.includes(:user).where(test_required: true, date: Date.today).where.not( :users => { :reader_id => nil }).pluck(:user_id, :users)

example_with_includes.each do |cycle_day|
  cycle_day.user.name
end
```

Without includes you would have a seperate query for getting the name of a single user belonging to that cycle day. However, includes preloaded all the users, therefore no further queries are required. So if you want to call a method on an associated object you should use includes.

You can use joins if you don't need to call any methods on the associated object. Example:

```
  example_with_joins = CycleDay.joins(:user).where(users: { role: 'admin' })
```

Imagine you are only interested in the attributes from cycle day, then there is no reason to load the entire associated table. The user is now so-called lazy loaded, you only have additional queries if you call methods on it (for example, retrieving its name).

Comment: couldn't get the data using this. What i got is  #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<CycleDay id: 144>, #<CycleDay id: 129>, #<CycleDay id: 112>]>   and what I wanted is [[144, "faiz"], [129, "ameeta"], [112, "shaista ansari"]]

Comment: That is the correct data. The only difference is that pluck goes over the results and returns all the attributes you want in an Array.

Comment: yeah, got it. but this also works=> CycleDay.includes(:user).where(test_required: true, date: Date.today).where.not( :users => { :reader_id => nil }).pluck(:user_id, 'users.name')

Comment: Certainly. Thats why I said you already answered your initial question. If an array is ok for what you want, you can just use this.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to accomplish this using the following, but still needs an explanation as I am new to rails

```
CycleDay.includes(:user).where(test_required: true, date: Date.today).where.not( :users => { :reader_id => nil }).pluck(:user_id, 'users.name')
```

i.e. using 'users.name' instead of :user

Comment: What kind of explanation do you want? Or in other words, what is unclear?

Comment: I tried a lot of things, :user.name , :user_name , user_name , user.name and lastly tried 'users.name' It is very difficult to find out the exact syntax in rails if you are not aware of it

Comment: I see. The difference is you try to retrieve an associated record. Normally you can use :<attribute>, but if you want to retrieve associations you need the SQL equivalent '<table_name>.<attribute_name>'.

Comment: This whole ruby/rails syntax is so damn confusing